On the choice of observables in linear response theory
For linear response theory I need two observables. The idea is to see how the change in one observable changes the other under weak perturbations in equilibrium state. Suppose I want to see the change in energies of the system, so one of my observables is the total energy. What choices do I have for my other observable? Can it be anything or there are certain limits to its choice?

The other observable can be any physical quantity that couples to the system in a way that might affect its energy. However, the choice should be physically meaningful and relevant to the system you're studying.
